# Exclude certain sites and subdomains from Google Alerts

Tags: google-alerts

Is there a way to exclude certain sites and subdomains from Google Alerts?

At the moment there are a couple of sites and a couple of subdoamins of other sites that are throwing up false positives (dev sites, our own blog running on subdomain.mydomain.com etc).

Answer (score 6):

[Google web search](http://www.google.com) allows you to use `-site:subdomain.mydomain.com` to exclude anything from subdomain.mydomain.com from the search results. [[source](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/tipstricks/all.html)]

So try creating a Google Alert with `-site:subdomain.mydomain.com` (add multiple instances of that for each site you want to exclude).  According to a discussion on the [Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/u3bRhApvnLM), that worked a few years ago.

You can also see from that discussion that a feature to allow using `site:subdomain.mydomain.com` (without the leading minus sign) to only send alerts from a specific web site has sometimes worked and sometimes been removed by Google.  So there's a possibility that `-site:subdomain.mydomain.com` no longer works in Google Alerts.

Comment: works currently, even multiple sites

Comment: still works now in 2021, thanks! :-)